# React native can't pass firebase key to component

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I have **firebase** key that I would like to pass from 1 component to the other, although it seems to just show as blank. In my `List.js` I can see I am able to get the key (through `this.props.item.key`) and display the key. But when I want pass it to `Editblog.js` it does not show anything.

```
List.js

const { blogDescription,  key, ownerId } = this.props.item.values;

Actions.edit_blog({ values: this.props.item.values });
```

I want to pass key to `Editblog.js` here I find `this.state.blogDescription` gives me the correct result but when I use `this.state.key` it shows up as blank.

```
Editblog.js


    this.state = {
      blogDescription: props.values.blogDescription,
      key: props.values.key,
      ownerId: props.values.ownerId
    };


<Text>{this.state.key}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most props on a JSX element are passed on to the component, however, there are two special props (`ref` and `key`) which are used by React, and are thus not forwarded to the component.

In your case you can pass the key as a different prop

```
Actions.edit_blog({ values: this.props.item.values, id: this.props.item.values.key });
```

And access it like this

```
this.state = {
  blogDescription: props.values.blogDescription,
  key: props.id,
  ownerId: props.values.ownerId
};


<Text>{this.state.key}</Text>
```

Comment: thank you bro, any chance you could help me with a different question

Comment: Sure, I'll see if I can help.

Comment: its this question -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50952813/react-native-img-src-as-undefined/50953312?noredirect=1#comment88927000_50953312

Comment: do you get it the problem or?